# I'm trying to use df2move conversion on a dataset, but am getting the error unable to find inherited method for function 'move'

Tags: r, move

I'm new to R and am currently using the df2move function to convert my dataframe into a move object. I have followed the formula for df2move, being : `df2move(df, proj, x, y, time, track_id = NULL, data = NULL, ...)` and am still getting an error. My code is as follows.

```
`
library("move")
library("moveVis")
library(styler) 
library(readxl)                                            
library(segmented)                                         
library("tidyverse")
library(RColorBrewer)                                      
library(readr)
library("lubridate")
library("argosfilter")

attach(jaguar_data)`
```

After attaching the dataframe, I receive this in my output:

```
`The following objects are masked from jaguar_data (pos = 3):

    country, Event_ID, individual.local.identifier..ID., individual.taxon.canonical.name, location.lat, location.long, study.name, tag.local.identifier, timestamp

The following objects are masked from jaguar_data (pos = 4):

    country, Event_ID, individual.local.identifier..ID., individual.taxon.canonical.name, location.lat, location.long, study.name, tag.local.identifier, timestamp

The following objects are masked from jaguar_data (pos = 7):

    country, Event_ID, individual.local.identifier..ID., individual.taxon.canonical.name, location.lat, location.long, study.name, tag.local.identifier, timestamp

The following objects are masked from moveVis:

    country, Event_ID, individual.local.identifier..ID., individual.taxon.canonical.name, location.lat, location.long, study.name, tag.local.identifier, timestamp
```

After inputting df2move:

```
`df2move(jaguar_data, proj, x = "location.long", y = "location.lat", time = "timestamp", track_id = "Event_ID")`
```

I am getting the error:

```
`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘move’ for signature ‘"numeric", "numeric", "POSIXct", "data.frame", "function"’`
```

I am confident the dataframe is correct and has the same format as an example dataset, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Does it have to do with the dataframe being masked, or the df2move function? Any info helps, thank you.

Comment: Try from a clean R session, but without attaching `jaguar_data`.

Comment: A reproducible example would help, maybe this can also be achieved with the function `move` ?